# PostgreSQL error : process still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 2676 of database 0

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.6, database-locking

We are not able to connect to a PostgreSQL instance and we have to restart the PostgreSQL service to connect to the instance, but we start getting the same error within a few days.

Logs show below error

```
2019-02-18 08:00:03.043 UTC [5053] postgres@utilitydbLOG:  process 5053 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 2676 of database 0 after 1000.431 ms
2019-02-18 08:04:04.486 UTC [5170] bucardo@bucardoLOG:  process 5170 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 2676 of database 0 after 1001.006 ms
2019-02-18 08:15:02.802 UTC [5445] postgres@utilitydbLOG:  process 5445 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 2676 of database 0 after 1000.425 ms
2019-02-18 08:30:02.844 UTC [5846] postgres@utilitydbLOG:  process 5846 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 2676 of database 0 after 1000.501 ms
2019-02-18 08:33:23.428 UTC [5940] bucardo@bucardoLOG:  process 5940 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 2676 of database 0 after 1001.265 ms
2019-02-18 08:45:02.869 UTC [6269] postgres@utilitydbLOG:  process 6269 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 2676 of database 0 after 1000.340 ms
2019-02-18 08:51:08.230 UTC [6478] dbuser@postgresLOG:  process 6478 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 2676 of database 0 after 1000.438 ms
```

When i check service status it shows below details

```
postgres: postgres utilitydb [local] startup waiting
postgres: postgres utilitydb [local] startup waiting
postgres: postgres utilitydb [local] startup waiting
postgres: postgres utilitydb [local] startup waiting
postgres: postgres utilitydb [local] startup waiting
postgres: postgres utilitydb [local] startup waiting
postgres: postgres utilitydb [local] startup waiting
postgres: postgres utilitydb [local] startup waiting
postgres: postgres utilitydb [local] startup waiting
```

I know I need to check for locks in the database but the information provided in logs is not so detailed. There is no such database with oid = 0 in PostgreSQL system tables.

How can I debug this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Something is holding an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the `pg_authid_rolname_index` index.

Nobody can use that index while this lock is held, and since this is the index on the table of users (`pg_authid`) that you need to search for a certain user name, no login can succeed.

You have fallen prey to a “denial of service” attack.

If there is an active database session holding the lock, kill it.

If the lock persists even if you restart the database, it must be a prepared transaction. Shut down the database and clean out the `pg_twophase` subdirectory of your data directory.

Secure your database better and change all superuser passwords.

Comment: Could you please mention the name of the table of users?

Comment: I have added it to my answer.

Comment: We run a maintenance job which reindexes and vacuum all tables (including system tables) of a database. is it possible that it can be the reason of ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock on the pg_authid_rolname_index ?

Comment: Yes, that could explain the problem. But if a `REINDEX` on that index takes more than a second, there is something wrong. How many users do you have? Why do you do that anyway?

Comment: We have 30 databases on an instance and 2 admin users and 2 normal users. Actually, we are reindexing all tables because we have a purge job which purges data older than a month. Its run every week. I think we have to specify particular tables during reindexing.

Comment: At least don't reindex your whole database in one transaction so that thr system tables are not locked for such a long time. If you don't delete more than 30-50% of your table, don't worry about the bloat. The space will be reused.

Comment: I am getting an error "process 24193 still waiting for ExclusiveLock on tuple (4,43) of relation 16537 of database 16388 after 1007.074 ms". How can i get exact row which is causing this lock.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ctid = '(4,43)';` The table name can be found with `SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 16537;`

Comment: I got a strange error in my testing server. When I see logs I find out this error "process 24193 still waiting for ExclusiveLock on tuple (4,43) of relation 16537 of database 16388". A cron runs in  15 minutes and connect to the database to gather some useful statistics. All cron instances were continued waiting due to a lock held by some process and thus all available connections were occupied and i was not able to connect to database and then i have to restart server.  How can i find out the process who were holding lock on the table at the first place?

Comment: It is the backend for whom all the others are waiting in `pg_locks`.

Comment: backend means what it can be. Can it be a full vacuum which runs in off hours or anything else? I need to reproduce this issue. How can I do so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to query `SELECT locker.pid FROM pg_locks AS locked JOIN pg_locks AS locker USING (virtualtransaction) WHERE NOT locked.granted AND locker.locktype = 'virtualxid';`.

Comment: I had to restart the server. So now all locks are gone. But how can i reproduce the same?

Comment: Lock a row that another transaction tries to lock.